# How to install nodejs modules on windows7?

Tags: linux, windows, node.js

I tried to install [MySQL](https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql) and [Canvas2D](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas) modules on windows 7, but there are linux commands at the build instructions, for example `make`, and there are some shell scripts too. I'm clueless. I have no idea how to install them on windows 7.
Sorry, I'm not an expert programmer, just a beginner, and I just want to try out nodejs with mysql and canvas2d.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: after installing node on windows just open command line and type npm , it should work automatically

Comment: ...unless a module you want needs to build native addons, like canvas does.  You need to [set up a build environment](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not install with `npm`?

NodeJS comes with Node Package Manager, a simple manager that uses repositories on [npmjs](http://npmjs.org/). It resolves dependencies, and no building is required.

```
npm install db-mysql
npm install canvas
```

I also suggest the mysql driver `mysql` instead of `db-mysql`.

```
npm install mysql
```

I found `mysql` to be easier to use.

Other commands you might want to know:

```
npm help
npm install
npm ls
npm update
npm link
npm publish
```

Comment: npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.

Comment: Canvas on GitHub's readme states `Unless previously installed you'll need Cairo. For system-specific installation view the Wiki.`

Answer (score 0):

Getting canvas to work on Windows is generally difficult (you need to install Python, Visual Studio Express + hotfixes etc). PhantomJs works easily on Windows, but little support for mysql afaik.