# MySQL driver for NodeDB: db-mysql gives node waf error on Mountain Lion

Tags: mysql, node.js, osx-mountain-lion, npm

So I am just starting out with node and npm on Mountain Lion, and have been following the Node Up and Running book to work with databases (http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001808/ch06.html#mysql).

When I tried sudo npm install -g db-mysql I get this message:

```
npm ERR! db-mysql@0.7.6 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the db-mysql@0.7.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the db-mysql package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

I've tried seeing if others have run into this. Most of the answers I've found have been focused on other installs ([During npm install socket.io I get error 127, node-waf command not found. How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778332/during-npm-install-socket-io-i-get-error-127-node-waf-command-not-found-how-to)), directed to Ubuntu (or Windows) users or simply advocate installing the mysql driver ([How to install nodejs modules on windows7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762789/how-to-install-nodejs-modules-on-windows7/14762890#14762890)).

The closest I've gotten is this solution in the project's issue thread, to just clone the source and replace node-waf with node-gyp: https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/issues/98. However the thread was started for ArchLinux, and a user ran into an error on Mountain Lion at the last step of the solution.

Is there a significant difference between the db-mysql and mysql drivers in practice? Are these the only options? If there is a reason to use db-mysql, how can I solve this install issue on Mountain Lion?

Comment: That driver is outdated and doesn't work with recent Node versions anymore, I'm afraid. There are other drivers, like [`node-mysql`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), but their semantics will be different from `db-mysql`.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I was curious about performance differences and pooling functionality with different drivers, but node-mysql looks good so far from my research so I will likely go with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am choosing node-mysql as the driver instead, I've found:

1. It's up to date, easier to install (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)
2. It works with the latest version MySQL cluster too, although MySQL cluter v7.3.1 and below use node-waf rather than node-gyp (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/ndbapi/en/ndb-nodejs-setup.html)
3. It supports collection pooling ([node-mysql connection pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731214/node-mysql-connection-pooling))